# is $f(x) = 2^x$ bijective?

Tags: inverse

I've been posed with the question "Why is $f$ not invertible?"

I have learned that $x^2$ is not bijective unless I restrict it to only use non-negative Reals.  However when I look at the curve of $2^x$ it looks to me that it passes the 1 unique x point throughout the whole chart.  However, I need to prove why $2^x$ is not invertible and rewrite it to make it invertible.  Do I need to restrict it from $R \rightarrow R^+$ ?  What else am I not understanding?  Thank you.

Comment: RyBoneCoder. Basics with drawings: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the function $f(x)=2^x$ is not surjective because:
$$\Im(f(x))=R^+$$
Being not surjective, $f(x)$ is not bijective. In this case we can't find the inverse because the inverse exists only when $f(x)$ is bijective.

If you restrict the codomain on $R^+$, the function is injective and surjective, so it's bijective. As noted before, the inverse is:
$$y=g(x)=\log_2(x)$$

Comment: So that means that if I restrict it to $R^+$ it is now invertible?

Comment: @Matteo You mean not surjective.

Comment: I think you mean $f$ is not surjective?

Comment: I have to a) explain why it's not invertible. b) rewrite to make it invertible, then find the inverse.  From what I understand doesn't something have to be surjective and injective to be invertible?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the error. Please see my edits.

Comment: Matteo, you had not edited the other occurrence where you say the function is not injective.

Answer (score 2):

Depend from where to where. But indeed, it's at least injective on $\mathbb R$, so on some co-domain, it will obviouly be bijective. Notice that whenever $a>0$, then $a^x$ is nothing else than $e^{x\ln(a)}$.

Comment: Your response is a little over my head.  Math is my weakness, I'm a cyber engineer and always struggle with math.  :)

Comment: @RyBoneCoder: If $f:X\to Y$ is injective, then $f:X\to f(X)$ is bijective. Here, since $2^x>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$, that $\lim_{x\to -\infty }2^x=0$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty }2^x=\infty $, then $x\mapsto 2^x$ is bijective $\mathbb R\to (0,\infty )$.